# retrieving jquery post data in php

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have the following js, posting data:

```
var data = jQuery(this).attr('data-wptl_ip');
jQuery('a').click(function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo $wplt_url ;?>/trackit.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {data: data},
    success: function(response){
console.log("success");
}
  });
});
```

On my php page i am tring to retrieve the post data by doing this:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

For some reason it's not getting the data. Can anyone see any problems with the above?

Comment: Because you are not posting `data`, you are posting `ip`. Try printing `$_POST['ip']`

Comment: sorry my mistake, updated.

Comment: may be url is wrong what do u see in console ??

Comment: url is correct, on trackit.php i send mail with the post variables in. i get the mail, but no data in it.

Comment: `var data = jQuery(this).attr('data-wptl_ip');` should be inside `jQuery('a').click(function() {`

Comment: @machineaddict - thank you! this was the issue! post as an answer, and i will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are posting field with name 'ip'.

You can get it so:

```
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
```

When you have problems with getting POST data then just print_r your POST array.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Then you can see all elements in $_POST.

EDIT:

Additionally replace

```
 console.log("success");
```

with

```
 console.log(response);
```

and you will get what you need.

Comment: please see updated question. when i do print_r($_POST); i get Array()

Answer (score 0):

Try this :  `$data = $_POST['ip'];` instead of `$data = $_POST['data'];` in your PHP page

also In ajax change `type: 'post',` to `type: "POST",`

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now

Answer (score 0):

Try [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) like

```
var data = jQuery(this).data('wptl_ip');
```

In **PHP**

try this,

```
 echo isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : "No data";
```

and to get all `post data` try,

```
 print_r($_POST);
```

**Also,**

I think you should `initialize` `data variable` in `click function`

Replace these lines

```
var data = jQuery(this).attr('data-wptl_ip');
jQuery('a').click(function() {
```

**by,**

```
jQuery('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = jQuery(this).attr('data-wptl_ip');//or jQuery(this).data('wptl_ip');
    jQuery.ajax({
```